# config.h.in not being used as a template

Tags: autotools, configure

I'm trying to supply a `config.h.in` to Autotools. The topic is covered in the Autoconf manual at [4.8.1 Configuration Header Templates](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/autoconf/autoconf_28.html). `config.h.in` looks like so:

```
/// \file config.h
/// \brief Library configuration file

#ifndef CRYPTOPP_CONFIG_H
#define CRYPTOPP_CONFIG_H

// define this if running on a big-endian CPU
#undef CRYPTOPP_BIG_ENDIAN

// define this if running on a little-endian CPU
#undef CRYPTOPP_LITTLE_ENDIAN

#endif  // CRYPTOPP_CONFIG_H
```

Our [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools/blob/master/configure.ac) includes the following for testing:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile] [libcryptopp.pc])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([configure.ac])

AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
LT_INIT

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG([C++])
AC_PROG_GREP
```

After `autoreconf` and `configure` runs, there is a `config.h`. The problem is, it does not follow the template `config.h.in`. It looks like a new `config.h` produced by the tools.

When I examine `config.log` I only see one mention of `config.h`. I can't find additional information about what is going on:

```
config.status:1172: creating Makefile
config.status:1172: creating libcryptopp.pc
config.status:1172: creating config.h
config.status:1401: executing depfiles commands
config.status:1401: executing libtool commands
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7):

> After `autoreconf` and `configure` runs, there is a `config.h`. The problem
>   is, it does not follow the template `config.h.in`. It looks like a new
>   `config.h` produced by the tools.

Take a look at your `config.h.in` at that point.  I think you'll be surprised.

The issue is that among the programs that `autoreconf` runs for you is [`autoheader`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/autoheader-Invocation.html#autoheader-Invocation), which *builds* a `config.h.in` based on what it finds in `configure.ac` (or `configure.in`).  Your subsequent `configure` then uses the new template, but nothing in particular about that is recorded in the configuration logs because the template already exists at that point.

That behavior is usually a welcome convenience, but if you want to supply your own, custom `config.h` template then you must avoid it being replaced when `autoreconf` is run (or when `autoheader` is run directly).  One way to do that is to avoid running those programs at all.  You may run other autotools programs, and if you decide to avoid `autoreconf` then it might be worth your while to script that.

On the other hand, Autoconf comes with a few built-in [macros to modulate `autoheader`'s behavior](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Autoheader-Macros.html#Autoheader-Macros).  In particular, `AH_TOP` and `AH_BOTTOM` may be useful to you for adding custom content to the automatically generated content.

On the third hand, if you want to provide your own template, written strictly by hand, and to avoid `autoheader` mucking with it, then it is useful to know that `autoheader` works with only the *first* header template named in your `configure.ac`, and you can name more than one.  Thus, you might add a dummy configuration header that your sources do not reference, so that `autoheader` can play with that without messing anything up:

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config_dummy.h config.h])
```

The Autotools will create that dummy config header and a template for it, but if your sources never reference it then that has no effect on the build.

Comment: @jww, I'm sorry you're having so much trouble.  I do note, however, that the page you linked is entitled "Using `autoconf` to Create configure", not "Using `auto`*`re`*`conf` [...]".  These are different tools, the latter having a wider scope.   Also, you appear to be looking at an outdated, third-party copy of the manual.  I'd recommend instead either the version packaged with your copy of the software, or [GNU's official copy](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/index.html).